# $f,g_1,...,g_k$ computable imply $h(x_1,...,x_n)=f(g_1(x_1,...,x_n),...,g_k(x_1,..,x_n))$ computable. Does the converse hold?

Tags: computer-science, computability

In the book "Computability, complexity and languages" by Davis, Sigal and Weyuker, the following

> $\bf THEOREM$
>
> If $f,g_1,...,g_k$ are computable functions, then $h(x_1,...,x_n)=f(g_1(x_1,...,x_n),...,g_k(x_1,..,x_n))$ is computable.

Is stated and proved. I'm interested in knowing if the converse is true, that is, given a computable composition, if each individual function is computable, I think this is true, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False, let $f$ be a constant function.  Then $h$ is computable but the $g_i$ can be arbitrarily bad. By a similar trick, we can arrange for $f$ to be also non-computable.

Comment: Damn... I'm slow. Thanks Andre (Now I think about it, the identity function is computable, so any composition of horrible invertible functions will be computable).

The only thing lacking would be to prove the existence of a non-computable function I think.

Comment: Which similar trick is that?

Comment: Existence is not hard, there are uncountably many functions and only countably many computable ones. Finding an *interesting* non-computable is another matter. But that has been done.

Comment: Trick, let $f$ be horrible if all inputs are even, and identically $0$ if any input is odd. Let $g_i$ be non-computable but always giving odd output. Then $h$ is identically $0$.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, Andre.

Comment: You are welcome.